Why are tags on Arqade now bold black and grey, instead of the light blue we always had? It looks awful in my opinion
Tags on Arqade had always looked in a shade of blue that was the same blue tone of the site itself. It all was very visually pleasing and coherent.
Now, since this week, tags are bold black and grey like this and they look awful in my opinion.
Could you revert this change, please? Does anyone like these black tags?


This is the third iteration on tag design (for Arqade at least). We used to have ones shaped like bullet casings until they standardised them to the SE default blue, back in 2018. Here's an old bug showing what they used to look like.

@Robotnik I liked and miss old style

@pinckerman - I would've said the same a few years ago, but now they seem dated IMO. If I was in charge of redesign (and I didn't have to answer to the community :P), I would actually de-emphasise them a bit, make them more link-like rather than button-like.

@Robotnik I just like to have a different ad hoc style, like our old "ask question" button

This isn't specific to Arqade, it's a Stack Exchange-wide change:
All tag labels suddenly appear in bold font
We don't have direct control over this.  I have not seen any Stack Exchange staff input on the matter yet either.  But it stems from Seeking feedback on tag colors update.

Staff have now posted an update to the 'seeking feeback post'. The rollout was poorly handled. There was the 'seeking feedback' post in November, then an update in Feb where they mentioned they were going with #3 (the bold one). They then launched the change in May, without any notice, nor a new post for feedback. They then locked the 'seeking feedback' one. See this community-led post for the tag feedback, and this one about the communication breakdown.
